# Renaming Rails migration file using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I'm trying to rename a migration files on a Rails app.

I wrote this code using JS.

```js
function pad2(n) {
  return n < 10 ? "0" + n : n;
}

fs.readdirSync(migrationFolder).forEach(async (file) => {
  const [migrationDate, ...rest] = file.split("_");



  setTimeout(() => {
    const date = new Date();

    const dateName =
      date.getFullYear().toString() +
      pad2(date.getMonth() + 1) +
      pad2(date.getDate()) +
      pad2(date.getHours()) +
      pad2(date.getMinutes()) +
      pad2(date.getSeconds());

    console.log(dateName);

    fs.rename(
      `migrate copy/${file}`,
      `./rename/${dateName}_${rest.join("_")}`,
      (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }, 5000);
});
```

but the date time format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` is just the same even though I added a 5 seconds delay.

Here's the sample output. Date time are the same:

[image]

Comment: You are creating multiple ```setTimeout``` almost simultaneously, and they all get scheduled to run after the same delay and means that they all execute at the same time. Because they all use the same ```date```, they all get the same timestamp. So here, you need to create a new ```Date``` inside each ```setTimeout```. This way, each function will have its own ```Date``` that gets the current time when it runs, not when it was scheduled.

Comment: ive tried it actually. same output. they have the same timestamp.

Comment: Have you try add **index**? Added in foreach ```forEach((file, index) => {..})```. Then on timer, it should be like this ```setTimeout(() => {..},5000 * index)```. This **index** represents the index of the current file in the array of files.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation holy**** it worked!! thank you so much. can you make it a answer so i can mark it? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an **index** to `forEach` and multiply it by the delay time. This way, each `setTimeout` call will be delayed by a different amount of time, so that the `Date` is updated for each file.

```
function pad2(n) {
 return n < 10 ? "0" + n : n;
}

fs.readdirSync(migrationFolder).forEach((file, index) => {
 const [migrationDate, ...rest] = file.split("_");

 setTimeout(() => {
  const date = new Date();

  const dateName =
    date.getFullYear().toString() +
    pad2(date.getMonth() + 1) +
    pad2(date.getDate()) +
    pad2(date.getHours()) +
    pad2(date.getMinutes()) +
    pad2(date.getSeconds());

  console.log(dateName);

  fs.rename(
    `migrate copy/${file}`,
    `./rename/${dateName}_${rest.join("_")}`,
    (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );
 }, 5000 * index); // Multiply the delay by the index
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. appreciate the help. I dont know why we need to multiply the delay but this works.

Comment: By doing ```5000 * index```, you're effectively adding a delay to each ```setTimeout``` call. The first item will have a delay of 0 seconds, the second item will have a delay of 5 seconds, the third item will have a delay of 10 seconds, and so on. This ensures that each ```setTimeout``` is delayed by a different amount of time, so the ```Date``` is updated for each file. Without this, all the ```setTimeout``` calls would be delayed by the same amount of time, and they would all use the same initial timestamp.

Comment: but isnt it delay for 5 seconds basically saying "run this code for every 5 sec" so timestamp has basically delay each time?

Comment: Yes, the ```setTimeout``` is indeed used to delay the execution of a function by a specified amount of time. ```5000 * index``` means that the function will be delayed by 5 seconds times the index of the current item in the loop. So, for the first item, there's no delay (because 5000 * 0 equals 0), for the second item, there's a delay of 5 seconds (because 5000 * 1 equals 5000), for the third item, there's a delay of 10 seconds (because 5000 * 2 equals 10000), and so on.

Comment: This means that the function will be executed for the first item immediately, for the second item after 5 seconds, for the third item after 10 seconds, and so on. And the ```Date``` is updated for each file, because the ```Date``` is created inside the function that's being delayed, and executed at different times for each file.